# How to get IWebBrowser2 of Internet Explorer running in "metro" mode?

Tags: c++, com, windows-runtime, iwebbrowser2, ihtmldocument2

I've got some C++ code, that uses ShellWindows to retrieve instances of IWebBrowser, but there is a problem, when IE is run in metro-mode - there are no instances in ShellWindows.
Are there any methods to retrieve IWebBrowser in this situation or may be there are some similar APIs, etc?
What I want is to retrieve the received document's content. May be there are some other ways to achieve this, when IE is in metro mode?

Comment: Not clear on what you're trying to do, but I've got some code that maybe is similar, but always fails because of a security exception (access denied) when trying to access another application's IE interfaces in a Windows Store app.

Comment: I've got a service, that analyzes web-content, so I need to get access to the loaded document and its structure. If You don't mind, I'd like to take a look at the code, may be there is something, that will help me.

Comment: Sorry, closed source. Like I said, it doesn't work either with a Windows Store application. It works fine with other apps, but there's clearly something different (unpublished) about the Windows Store applications and how they host IE.

Comment: This kind of process interop is entirely *verboten* in Store applications.  Enforced by ShellWindows, it doesn't enumerate the instances that run in the WinRT sandbox.  You only see the desktop instances.  You cannot make this work.

Comment: So, are there any other ways to communicate with IE?